# boost MPL::vector not recognized and Meta State Machine (MSM) transition table not defined

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator, template-meta-programming, state-machine

I'm trying to learn boost's meta state machine (MSM) library.

Following the simple state machine example in http://redboltz.wikidot.com/simple-state-machine, I face some problems:

1. I have a problem in defining the state machine's "transition table" using `boost::mpl::vector`.

   ```
   // Transition table
   struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
       //          Start   Event   Next    Action      Guard
       msmf::Row < State1, Event1, End,    msmf::none, msmf::none >
   > {};
   ```
2. The Qt Creator IDE does no detect and auto complete the `mpl::vector` (it only recognizes the numbered versions i.e. `mpl::vector0/1`...)!!!
3. The code compiles (with no error) but it crashes when I run it (on line 203 of `state_machine_def.hpp` which is about the transition handler of the FSM)
4. I am using Boost 1.66 on Windows 7 with Qt 5.9.0 MinGW 32 bit compiler.
5. I have added boost's path to my include path (since MSM & MPL are header only libraries)

#### Questions

> **Q1** - Why does not my system recognize the `boost::mpl::vector`?
>
> **Q2** - Replacing `mpl::vector` with `mpl::vector1` (which is recognized by my IDE, QtCreator) does not solve my problem (run time crash)

Reminder: the SM in the above example has only ONE transition entry.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. what is the problem?
2. that's okay. The completion engine is probably misconfigured or using an old standard - meaning it doesn't understand all the boost headers.

   `mpl::vector` is literally just a type-list, so there's no "intellisense" to expect at all: You can only give it types, and there is no way for the compiler to predict what types you wanted.

   `mpl::vector<int, double, std::string>` is equally valid as `mpl::vector<>`.
3. the things that's important is that your compiler understands it. So, apparently it does.

   If you have a runtime error, find out information about the crash. The code from the link

   - works fine with Boost 1.60 on MSVC http://rextester.com/OYVFX99145,
   - with GCC on Boost 1.66  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c11ec88771f0a33
   - with Clang on Boost 1.66  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a78535220afc640d
4. See ^
5. Yeah, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled

> **Q1**

It does recognize `boost::mpl::vector` or it wouldn't have compiled. See 2.

> **Q2**

There's no difference: Both model the exact same type sequence. One is variadic, and the other "number" (i.e. having fixed length): https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending your time and elaborating on all of the points;
I found the problem; MSM requires that the "transition_table" struct be defined exactly as mentioned. I had slightly misspelled it and thus I got the run-time error; 
I've put this comment here in case anyone else encounters the same problem.
Your answers were helpful and let me proceed to look for the problem elsewhere.
In a big SM such misspellings might happen & the corresponding state machine would compile & only crash in "run time". Is there any other way to inspect and find such problems when using boost::msm??

Comment: One final question: The boost::msm documentation did not emphasize that the “transition_table” or the “on-entry” & “on_exit” structs have to be defined exactly as mentioned (or maybe I've missed it). 
Is there any document, mentioning the "synactical" points that should be respected when working with boost::msm?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @qwa I agree that if misspellings result in runtime failures, that might be a usability bug. OTOH, I haven't seen your particular misconfiguration, so it might have made perfect sense (perhaps the crash was a simple infinite loop etc.) My crystal ball doesn't work well enough to judge that, but if you're not sure you could report the issue with the library maintainers

Comment: The docs just say "guard: a boolean operation being able to prevent the triggering of a transition which would otherwise fire." - the concepts page also describes it as a "Boolean operation" but that doesn't seem to be further defined. I'd just follow the [sample instructions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#d0e406)